# has anyone else had cypress.io test start failing as of Feb 18, 2019?

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js, cypress

With no changes to the tests or tested environment, cypress.io tests that ran successfully up until Feb 18, 2019 are now failing with error.

Cypress.io is version 3.1.5

The tests are run by jenkinsfile as:

```
sh "npx cypress run --browser chrome  --reporter mocha-multi-reporters   --reporter-options configFile=config-v1-smoke.json  --spec \"cypress/integration/smoke/*.js\""
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'passes' of undefined
    at Spec.Base.epilogue (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/svn_ci/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:318:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Runner.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Reporter.emit (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:239:55)
    at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:296:22)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:237:36)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at /var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'passes' of undefined
    at Spec.Base.epilogue (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/svn_ci/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:318:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Runner.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Reporter.emit (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:239:55)
    at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:296:22)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:237:36)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at /var/jenkins_home/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:18
```

0:9)

Comment: I noticed that when I run the tests, that --spec "xxxxxx*.js" does behaving the way it has in past.  It does not have the correct # of tests.  It is globbing all tests.

Answer (score 4):

mocha@6.0.0 was released on 2019-02-18.
By downgrading mocha from to last release mocha@5.2.0, the problem is alleviated.  With mocha@5.2.0, the correct set of cypress.io tests are run as specified in --spec.

Something in mocha@6.0.0 is creating test spec glob problem for cypress.io with mocha reporting.

Answer (score 1):

Washingons comment with regards to the glob problem is incorrect. Mocha 6 requires a stat collector to be instantiated.

I’ve now updated, tested and released updated modules that fix this with mocha 6, but also retains backwards compatibility with mocha 5 and earlier versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-multi-reporters
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporters

[Example against Mocha 5](https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/32)
[Example against Mocha 6](https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/22/)

the changes required are minimal

`npm i mocha-junit-reporters`

`npm i cypress-multi-reporters`

in reporterOpts.json

```
{
  "reporterEnabled": "mocha-junit-reporters, mochawesome",
  "mochaJunitReportersReporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "cypress/reports/junit/test_results[hash].xml",
    "toConsole": false
  },
  "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/reports/mocha",
    "quiet": true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "html": false,
    "json": true
  }
}
```

in cypress.json

```
{
  ...
  "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "configFile": "reporterOpts.json"
  }
```

See https://github.com/YOU54F/cypress-docker-typescript/pull/22/files

Hopefully the PR's will be merged in the source repo's soon but for now, enjoy

Comment: my fix has now been merged in mocha-junit-reporter now, v1.23.0